# bot.loop.create_task function does not work- Python Discord Bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I have a Discord Bot program that needs to send a message when I call a function, but the code gets stuck on `bot.loop.create_task`.

Here you go for my code below:

**bot.py**

```
async def send_msg(word):
    global bot
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    ch=bot.get_channel(channel)
    print(ch)
    await ch.send("The word "+word+" has been spoken :)")


def action(word):
    bot.loop.create_task(send_msg(word))
```

**send_msg.py**

```
    from bot import action
    action(word)
```

Comment: If you want to actually create a function that sends a message within discord (without a discord bot, tbh I don't see why you need it) you can take a look at one of my [gists](https://gist.github.com/Kwieeciol/50cca99f495178cf6c49593e03dfff54)

Comment: I will try your solution, thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Just create the task before or after the bot.run command in the main file.

```
async def send_msg(word):
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    ch=bot.get_channel(00000000000000)
    print(ch)
    await ch.send("The word "+word+" has been spoken :)")

bot.loop.create_task(send_msg(word))
bot.run()
```

I'd recommend doing it before

EDIT(sorry for not double checking):
I've just noticed your function is in the main file but you're importing it in another file that isn't the main file? You could use cogs for this

Comment: Thanks a lot, but won't that perform the function?

Comment: Yeah, it would perform the function.

Comment: Ok but I would like to run the function only when send_msg.py calls it. Do you have another idea?

Comment: Did you want to call it when the bot starts up? You can just import the send_message function and then create the task in the main file

Comment: Wait, I think I see your issue, let me edit real quick

Comment: Thanks for your edit (we really had bad timing with the maintenance ). I am not very familiar with cogs. Can you show me the code I'm supposed to do please?

Comment: @Sulfurick There should be some tutorials on YouTube